# Objective C: How to present modal view controller from appdelegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

I am in the appdelegate of my application. How can I add a modal view controller in the "didfinishlaunching" method?

I tried the following but did not work

```
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc]init];
[self.tabController.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

EDIT:
I changed my implementation to the following

```
self.tabController.selectedViewController 
= [self.tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc]init];
[self.tabController.selectedViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

I checked that the 'selected view controller' is not null... however I am still not able to get the output I needed. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: did you see anything in the debugger when you tried the code above? If so, what was there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming tabController and navigationController are not nil, the applicationDidFinishLaunching may be too soon to display the modal view controller.

1. Make sure you put that code after you make the window key and visible. `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`
2. If that does not work try listening for the `UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` for that window
3. You can try delaying presentation of that modal a few seconds using [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Along with upvote, giving a Salute to your answer. It saves my lot of time to make it work with other logic which I was thinking so far.
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; works like charm