# Present view controller from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm attempting to present a view controller from the app delegate with this code:

```
- (void)interstitialViewControllerRequestSucceeded:(UIViewController *)interstitialViewController
{
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:(UIViewController *)interstitialViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

It will display the interstitial on the initial view controller but none of the others. I want it to display on every one attached to a navigation controller.

How can I modify this code to achieve that goal?

Comment: So what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Duplicate this quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430179/appdelegate-rootviewcontroller-and-presentviewcontroller

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can also try:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]
```

How I use it:

```
#define ROOTVIEW [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]
[ROOTVIEW presentViewController:interstitialViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: That has the same behavior. Only works on the initial view controller. How do I get the current navigation controller and present the view from there?

Comment: @Yar, that's bad practice.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3 version for checked response :

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 5 and up

Check this:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
```