# How to present iOS Keyboard extension using presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

My goal is to present the iOS Keyboard with the method `presentViewController:animated:completion` whenever the keyboard has successfully instantiated, taking advantage of the smooth upward animation.

Some very brief background: the keyboard extension project is written in Objective-C, with `KeyboardViewController.h/.m` handling the logic and some basic view layout from a `inputView.xib`.

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430179/appdelegate-rootviewcontroller-and-presentviewcontroller), several of the the answers suggested using the approach of calling `presentViewController` from `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController`. The problem is, as this is an iOS extension, when I try to replicate this method, I get the error that `sharedApplication` is not available. I was wondering if a workaround exists where I could present the Keyboard with the method `presentViewController`, either somehow via itself or via a `super`? In my current attempts, calling `[self presentViewController: self...]` causes an exception.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done.

One can actually acquire a reference to `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` easily, the most straightforward (though liable to get you rejected in App Store review) would be:

```
  Class appClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIApplication");
  id app = [appClass performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
```

Running on the iPhone 5 simulator, `[app keyWindow]` returns `nil` when called from the principal input view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method.

`[UIApplication windows]`, however, does not, so we could try

```
[[[app windows].firstObject rootViewController] presentViewController:self
                                                                   animated:YES
                                                                 completion:nil];
```

...but it just throws an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
>   modally an active controller .'

Walking the view hierarchy starting from `UIApplication windows]` reveals an interesting fact: the window of our `UIInputViewController` *isn't in this window hierarchy*. `self.view.window` returns a separate `_UIHostedWindow` with no `superView`.

Furthermore, There is no variation across apps of the addresses in memory of windows returned from `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Conclusion: the `UIApplication` we get from `sharedApplication` is the one for our process, not for the host process. Presenting on views and windows it owns therefore is pointless, because its views aren't visible to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough investigation Ben. I'll leave this question up for a few more days, and if no one says to the contrary I'll award you the bounty mark this as answer.